# Exchange EWS Api - Get calendar appointment by category

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am currently developing an app which checks one or more users calendars for appointments/meetings under a specific category.

Being new to working with EWS, i have been trying to find a solution as to get a Calendar item (appointment or meeting) by Category or determine if an appointment has a specific category. I currently have the following code so far (exService = ExchangeService object):

```
foreach (Appointment a in exService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new ItemView(int.MaxValue)))
            {
                //Need to check if appointment has category f.x.: "SMS"
            }
```

Does anybody know a way to acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your querying Appointments you want to use FindAppointments and a calender-view rather then using FindItems this will ensure that any recurring appointments are expanded eg see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx

to use categories all you need to do is something like

```
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(60);
        const int NUM_APPTS = 1000;

        // Initialize the calendar folder object with only the folder ID. 
        CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());

        // Set the start and end time and number of appointments to retrieve.
        CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);

        // Limit the properties returned to the appointment's subject, start time, and end time.
        cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End,AppointmentSchema.Categories);

        // Retrieve a collection of appointments by using the calendar view.
        FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe first " + NUM_APPTS + " appointments on your calendar from " + startDate.Date.ToShortDateString() +
                          " to " + endDate.Date.ToShortDateString() + " are: \n");
        foreach (Appointment a in appointments)
        {
            if (a.Categories.Contains("Green"))
            {
                Console.Write("Subject: " + a.Subject.ToString() + " ");
                Console.Write("Start: " + a.Start.ToString() + " ");
                Console.Write("End: " + a.End.ToString());
            }                
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```